# Div background-image not appearing? Image source has been checked multiple times

Tags: css, image, url, html, background

I am trying to setup a simple div which I have done many times in the past but something is going wrong... Here is a fiddle of my code.

http://jsfiddle.net/psychoticpanda/HTtRs/

Either I am going insane, hitting a glitch in something or it is too late for me to code after a 13 hour day of class... Please help me feel sane and help me out! The image works when it is used as `<img src="(IMAGE)" />` but when I use it as a `background-image: url("image");` in CSS it doesn't work...? I need it to be a background for buttons to go on top without problems! Please help...

Comment: are you sure the relative path from the location of the css file is the same one as the one in the img element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `url()` contents are a relative path it is derived from the path of the stylesheet location.  So if your stylesheet is `/css/file.css` and the rule is `url(image/filename.png)` it will look for it in `/css/image/filename.png`.  You should probably use an absolute path for the image.

Comment: Really..? Wonder how I never ran into this before but then again I just recently started writing code so this is only like my third project. How exactly would I use an absolute path? I currently have my folders setup as... css, images, js and then the main map.html enclosed in a general folder.

Comment: @psychoticpanda absolute path starts with a slash (or is a fully qualified url such as `http://example.com/`)

Comment: hmm I figured it was that just wasn't 100% sure, so how would I go about doing an absolute path without having the image hosted on a server and just to test it locally for now?

Comment: @psychoticpanda you might have missed the "or" in my example, but `url(/path/to/images/from/document/root/image.png)` is an absolute path

Comment: The absolute path would be `http://example.com/images/map.png`. But given your file structure, you can also change your relative path to `url("../images/map.png")`. The two `../` means "go up one folder".

Comment: @ralph.m, no if it starts with a slash it's still absolute

Comment: Wow thanks so much Ralph! You really just saved me (more) hours of further researching this problem. Never would of known that is how url() is read. Thanks again!

Comment: @Explosion Pills Hehe, I've watched enough flame wars over the definition of "absolute' not to get involved in another, but it seems to come down to one's definition. Some reserve "absolute" as referring to the URI that will work from anywhere, in any context. I used to call URLs beginning with a slash "absolute", but was browbeaten into calling them "root relative" URLs. Meh. The important thing is that the path works.

Comment: @ralph.m well I don't want to get into a flame war either, but that's wrong.  It's an absolute path.  There is a path *part* of the URL.  You can use a URI to specify the source as well and it will have an absolute path, or you can specify it with an absolute path (that is not a URL).

Answer (score 0):

Your file path of `url("images/map.png")` assumes that your `images` folder is in the same folder as the CSS file. If that's not the case, your path is incorrect. If it **is** the case, the next thing I'd try (but consider this anyway) is to use `background:` instead of `background-image:`—which, on its own, doesn't provide any information about its positioning or whether or not you want the image repeated.